# Are you required to call Recv until you get io.EOF when interacting with grpc.ClientStreams?

Tags: go, grpc

Suppose I define the following gRPC service:

```
service Library {
  rpc Search(SearchBookRequest) returns (stream SearchBookResponse) {} 
}

message SearchBookRequest {
  string term = 1;
  int32 max_results = 2;
}

message SearchBookResponse {
  int32 book_id = 1;
}
```

It streams search results back up to a specified maximum. When interacting with the service via gRPC's Go API, am I allowed to do something like this?

```
for i:=0; i<maxResults; i++ {
  search_result, err := stream.Recv()
  if err == io.EOF {
    // Note: If `maxResults` are returned this will never be reached.
    break
  }
  if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("search error: %v", err)
  }
  fmt.Printf("Book-ID: %d\n", search_result.BookId)
}
```

Or am I required to keep calling `Recv` until I get `io.EOF` to ensure that gRPC properly cleans up all its resources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is correct.

You can exit on errors. You don't need to wait for an EOF.

---

Edit: the answer above is incomplete.

The caller should keep receiving until an error, otherwise there could be leaks. There are other ways to avoid leaks, like canceling the context. See https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/grpc#ClientConn.NewStream for details.

Comment: Do you know if this is documented anywhere?

Comment: I know you can exit on errors; but in the case of no errors, are you allowed to omit a final call to `Recv` if you know the result will be `io.EOF`?

Comment: It depends on your exact setup:
- If you close the ClientConn then the underlying transport is closed as well and the server will stop handling the stream.
- If you set up the stream with a deadline on the client side, but omit closing the connection, the server will keep the connection open until the deadline is exceeded
- If you do not set a deadline on the client side and do not close the client connection, GRPC will poll the underlying connection with backoff based on the [keepalive options](https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/grpc/keepalive#ServerParameters) used to create the server.

Comment: @RyanBurn Per the documentation here (https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/grpc#ClientConn.NewStream), it is improper to just stop receiving from the stream if you somehow know the next message should be io.EOF.  Unless you do one of the other things (cancel the stream context or close the ClientConn), resources will be leaked.