# What's the best way to determine when an RPC session ends using a StreamClientInterceptor?

Tags: go, grpc, opentracing

When writing a [StreamClientInterceptor](https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/grpc#StreamClientInterceptor) function, what's the best way to determine when an invoker finishes the RPC? This is straightforward enough with unary interceptors or on the server-side where you're passed a [handler](https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/grpc#StreamHandler) that performs the RPC, but it's not clear how best to do this on the client-side where you return a [ClientStream](https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/grpc#ClientStream) that the invoker then interacts with.

One use case for this is instrumenting OpenTracing, where the goal is to start and finish a span to mark the beginning and end of the RPC.

A strategy I'm looking into is having the stream interceptor return a decorated ClientStream. This new ClientStream considers the RPC to have completed if any of the interface methods `Header`, `CloseSend`, `SendMsg`, `RecvMsg` return an error or if the `Context` is cancelled. Additionally, it adds this logic to `RecvMsg`:

```
func (cs *DecoratedClientStream) RecvMsg(m interface{}) error {
    err := cs.ClientStream.RecvMsg(m)
    if err == io.EOF {
        // Consider the RPC as complete
        return err
    } else if err != nil {
        // Consider the RPC as complete
        return err
    }
    if !cs.isResponseStreaming {
        // Consider the RPC as complete
    }
    return err
}
```

It would work in most cases, but my understanding is that an invoker isn't required to call `Recv` if it knows the result will be `io.EOF` (See [Are you required to call Recv until you get io.EOF when interacting with grpc.ClientStreams?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42915337/are-you-required-to-call-recv-until-you-get-io-eof-when-interacting-with-grpc-cl/42939914#42939914)), so it wouldn't work in all cases. Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a very similar issue where I wanted to trace streaming gRPC calls. Other than decorating the stream as you mentioned yourself, I was not able to find a good way to detect the end of streams. That is, until I came across the stats hooks provided by grpc-go (https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/grpc/stats). Even though the stats API is meant for gathering statistics about the RPC calls, the hooks it provides are very helpful for tracing as well.

If you're still looking for a way to trace streaming calls, I have written a library for OpenTracing instrumentation of gRPC, using the stats hooks: 
 https://github.com/charithe/otgrpc. However, please bear in mind that this approach is probably not suitable for systems that create long-lived streams.